# appendTo не работает в IE8

Tags: jquery, javascript, internet-explorer

Ситуация такова:

есть функция вида

```
function pager(element) {
    var alphabet = 'абвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщэюя';
    for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
        $('<a href="#" onclick="onDataNeed("' + alphabet[i] + '")" target="_self">' + alphabet[i] + '<a>').appendTo(element);
    }
}
```

есть страница, содержащая пустой div. При просмотре страницы в Opera и Chrome div заполняется буквами. В IE8 - нет. Кто что может посоветовать?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно тег a закрыть.

```
function pager(element) {
    var alphabet = 'абвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщэюя';
    for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
        $('<a href="#" onclick="onDataNeed("' + alphabet[i] + '")" target="_self">' + alphabet[i] + '</a>').appendTo(element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Все верно, тэг  нужно закрывать.
А чтобы быстрее работало, сделайте так:

```
function pager(element) {
    var alphabet = 'абвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщэюя';
    var data = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
        data += '<a href="#" onclick="onDataNeed("' + alphabet[i] + '")" target="_self">' + alphabet[i] + '</a>';
    }
    $(element).html($(element).html() + '' + data);
}
```

Comment: А ещё лучше собирать код в массив, а потом склеивать. Про пользу последней строчки сомневаюсь, читабельность явно страдает по сравнению с appendTo.

Comment: А лучше чем? Тем, что слово прикольное? Насчет последней строчки - можно без jquery, тогда будет лучше читаться: $(element)[0].innerHTML += ''+data;